# How to remove the space at the begin of read Stream via BufferReader

Tags: java, filestream

I have try follow snippet to read file

```
mFileReader = new FileReader(mAutoUpgradeFile);
mBufferedReader = new BufferedReader(mFileReader);
mStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
String line=null;
while( null != (line=mBufferedReader.readLine()) ){
   mStringBuilder.append(line);
   Log.d(TAG,"read line ="+line+"\n");
}
```

The content of **mAutoUpgradeFile**

```
aaaaa
bbbbbb
ccccccccc
dddddddddd
```

Output via readLine

read line =<kbd>space</kbd> aaaaa

read line = bbbbbb

## update 2015-12-18 first time

print the ASCII of the first byte of *line*
It's same line below:

[image]

What's **65279** mean in this situation？

## update 2015-12-18 Second time

**65279** may be Introduced by *UTF-8* + *BOM* format

change encoding format to *UTF-8* + *! BOM* format

This issue resolved

Thanks everybody.

Comment: This is probably the fastest way to do it. `line = !line.isEmpty() && line.charAt(0) == ' ' ? line.substring(1) : line;`

Answer (score 0):

[String#trim()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()) removes any leading and trailing whitespace from a string.

> Returns a copy of the string, with leading and trailing whitespace omitted.

Besides you can use [String#replaceFirst(String regex, String replacement)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

> Replaces the first substring of this string that matches the given regular expression with the given replacement.

And use a regex like :

```
line= line.replaceFirst("^ ", "");
```

Comment: While it would probably fix the problem, i think OP might be more curios as to why there's a space at all.

Comment: Hi @rakeb.mazharul , thanks your feedback,   I have update the questions describe

Answer (score 0):

Using `String#trim()` method or `line.replaceAll("^\\s+|\\s+$", "")` will trim the whitespace from both the end.

For left side trim:

```
line.replaceAll("^\\s+", "");
```

For right right trim:

```
line.replaceAll("\\s+$", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

If the "xxx" trace prints out the first character read from the line, then you have a line which begins by the unicode char 65279 (which I don't know what represents), so it is not actually a *blank* nor whitespace character.

If you know by certain which character ranges you want to allow when reading a line, I recommend you to trim the leading ocurrences that slip out of that ranges.

For example: To trim all the leading characters out of A-Z, a-z, and 0-9:

```
line=line.replaceFirst("[^a-zA-Z0-9]*", "");
```